# Calculate the distance between two 3d points in screen coordinates

Tags: shader, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

Given the **Point A** with the coordinates `gl_FragCoord.xy`, I have to find the distance to the **Center** of the cube face to which it belongs in screen coordinates.

Specifically what I need is the formula to convert the **Center** of every face of the cube in screen coordinates, in order to compare it with `gl_FragCoord`.

This the fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

varying vec2 v_uv;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(v_uv.x, v_uv.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

This the vertex shader:

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_uv;

uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_projection;

varying vec2 v_uv;

void main() {
  v_uv = a_uv;

  gl_Position = u_projection * u_view * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't calculate the center of the face in the shader, instead you have to supply it to the shader as `attribute vec3 a_face_center;` The good news is that you can calculate the distance to the center in the vertex shader, which will then be interpolated per-fragment.